# How to refresh a Facebook access token for a specific Facebook user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token, facebook-authentication, facebook-authorization

We have an application that allows users to associate *multiple* Facebook accounts. They use our software to, among other things, post selectively to those accounts.

Of course, the access tokens expire and we need to refresh them. However, since we have multiple tokens for multiple accounts, we need to refresh a very specific account.

If we simply throw the user into the auth flow, they will refresh to whichever Facebook account they are currently authenticated (or happen to log in to), which may not be the one we need to refresh.

**Is there anyway to place the user into the auth flow with a hint so that they can log in to the correct Facebook account and refresh the specific token we need refreshed?** Presumably, this would override any current session they might have with Facebook as well.

I can understand that this is sort of counter-intuitive to the normal use case (i.e., keeping the auth flow very seamless for the user), but nonetheless, it is our scenario.

If this is unsupported, does anyone have any ideas about alternate approaches?

Comment: What are those `other accounts`? And are you using the feed dialog to post, since posting to other accounts(assuming other accounts means user accounts) is not possible now? Then only we could help you out with your situation

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean, but if the user signs in to his main account, you can check his associated FB accounts access token expiry date. Then just check if it expired and give the user a hint to login to this account.

Comment: People use our software to manage many Facebook accounts - e.g., my personal account and my business account. If my business account's token expires, I would like to be able to send the user through the authorization flow to re-authorize the business account. However, if they are currently logged into their personal account, I will not get the correct token re-authorized. If I could send the user to the authorization flow with a hint to use the business's login, then the user would get the correct token re-authorized.